# Maximum/minimum problem of integers

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

Let $f$ be the function such that
$$f(x,y,z,w)=x+w, \quad x,y,z,w\in{\Bbb Z}$$ 
where 
$$
x+y+z+w=400,
$$
and $x<y<z<w$. How can I find the maximum of $f$?

I think the key point is to use $x<y<z<w$. I guess $98<99<101<102$ should be a choice. But I have no idea about how to give a proof.

---

[EDITED:] According to answers, $\max f=+\infty$. What's the minimum of $f$? I think there should be a bound. Playing around the examples, I think $\min f$ should be given by $(98,99,101,102)$. Any examples "better" than this?

Comment: But $24+25+26+27$ is not $400$.

Comment: It should be "*the* function", not "*a* function"; there's only one such function.

Comment: Why don't you set y and z equal to zero? I think that will give you your maximum.

Comment: @Ben x < y < z < w, so y and z cannot both be 0.

Comment: @Goku, what about 0 < 1 < 2 < 397? Or -2< -1 < 0 < 403?  Experiment a bit, and then you might gain some insight?

Comment: In your edited question, $w>100$ and $x<100$ must be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sum of all four variables is constant, maximizing $x+w$ is equivalent to minimizing $y+z$. Since you can make $x,y,z$ as negative as you like and then use $w=400-(x+y+z)$, $f$ is unbounded and has no maximum.

Comment: Yes. You don't suppose OP meant for the variables to be positive, do you?

Comment: @Gerry: They might, I don't know. It's certainly not unheard of that people pose problems that don't have a solution. Note that the OP didn't object to amWhy suggesting negative values. In any case, no harm done if the resulting experience is that badly posed questions lead to unhelpful answers :-)

Comment: @Gerry: The answer was accepted, so it seems $\mathbb Z$ was indeed intended.